# "Cannot create cython.array from NULL pointer" error when indexing an HDF5 dataset in Python

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am using the h5py package to extract data from an HDF5 file and manipulate it using Python. There is a dataset called "Bodies" in the file h5Test.pph, so I first set up with:

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('h5Test.pph', 'r')
bodies = f['Bodies']
```

From there I am able to access most indices in `bodies` (e.g. 0, 4, 1000), but for some reason `bodies[2]` and `bodies[3]` result in this error

```
ValueError: Cannot create cython.array from NULL pointer
```

I have used the h5dump command line tool to confirm that these entries exist, and nothing looks strange about the data. I am new to both HDF5 files and posting on stack overflow, so please let me know if there is any additional information that would be useful.

Edit for additional information:

`numpy.shape(bodies)` returns

```
(10689,)
```

and `numpy.dtype(bodies)` returns

```
dtype({'names':['ID','Name','Orientation','Color','Position','Velocity','Angular velocity','Change in w in body frame','Force','Torque','Additional force','Temperature','Angular momentum','Principal moments of inertia','Mass','Volume','Scale','Shape','Group','Material','Mode','Lua control functions','Monitored','Stress'], 'formats':[[('ID', '<i8')],[('data', 'O')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('w', '<f4')],[('red', '<f4'), ('green', '<f4'), ('blue', '<f4'), ('alpha', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],'<f4',[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')],'<f4','<f4','<f4',[('ID', '<i8')],[('ID', '<i8')],[('ID', '<i8')],'<u4','O','u1',{'names':['[0, 0]','[0, 1]','[0, 2]','[1, 0]','[1, 1]','[1, 2]','[2, 0]','[2, 1]','[2, 2]'], 'formats':['<f4','<f4','<f4','<f4','<f4','<f4','<f4','<f4','<f4'], 'offsets':[0,12,24,4,16,28,8,20,32], 'itemsize':36}], 'offsets':[0,8,16,32,48,60,72,84,96,108,120,132,136,148,160,164,168,172,180,188,196,200,216,217], 'itemsize':253})
```

Also for example, `bodies[0]` returns

```
((1487,), (b'compactor_disk',), (0., 0., 0., 1.), (0.38671875, 0.38671875, 0.38671875, 0.5859375), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0.), (-0.72721094, 0.20889588, -41.384094), (0.01420393, 0.34127262, 0.05411187), (0., 0., 0.), 0., (0., 0., 0.), (2.5448524e-06, 2.5513377e-06, 4.367137e-06), 0.00292779, 3.9037224e-07, 10., (14954,), (1736,), (1738,), 16, array([(22769,)], dtype=[('ID', '<i8')]), 1, (1035920.44, -53857.83, 874206.7, 84758.26, 1571146.4, -36402.49, -16.688602, -17.05545, 553.0667))
```

Using the command `h5dump -d Bodies h5Test.pph` yields a rather long output, but one of the elements that gave the error is this one:

```
   (2): {
         {
            1489
         },
         {
            "lid"
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
         },
         {
            0.386719,
            0.386719,
            0.386719,
            0.585938
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0.3
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0
         },
         {
            0,
            0,
            0
         },
         0,
         {
            0,
            0,
            0
         },
         {
            2.59831e-06,
            2.60443e-06,
            4.41639e-06
         },
         0.00282375,
         3.765e-07,
         10,
         {
            15293
         },
         {
            1736
         },
         {
            1738
         },
         16,
         (),
         0,
         {
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         }
      },
```

Comment: Did you mean `bodies = f['Bodies']`?  You need to be accurate when copying the code you used.  Full error messages are also useful.  Remember, we aren't looking over your shoulder, and can't (or at least should have to) guess.  If `bodies` is a dataset, it would be good if you showed its `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: That's correct, my apologies! I have changed it to f['Bodies'] and added some more information.

Comment: I wonder if the 3rd to the last field is giving problems 'Lua control functions'.  In [0] it is an array, in [2] I see '()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with some HDF5 and h5py basics. When you enter `bodies = f['Bodies']`, the return (`bodies`) is a h5py dataset object that behaves like a NumPy array. You get details of the dataset from your `shape` and `dtype` calls.

This dataset is similar to a recarray with 10689 rows of heterogeneous data. The dtype of each field(column) is defined by a dictionary of 2 keys: `'names'` and `'formats'` -- they work as a paired list. For example, Field 1 is an integer array named `'ID'`; Field 2 is an Python object named `'Name'`; Fields 3 an array of 4 floats named 'Orientation', and the array members are: `'x', 'y', 'z', 'w'` respectively. This continues down the names/format pairs. Some of the fields are much more complicated: the last one, `'Stress'` references another dictionary, and `'Lua control functions'` is another Python Object. (HDF5 supports data structures that don't map to standard NumPy datatypes -- in these situations h5py uses them in recarrays -- examples include nd.arrays, Lists, Dictionaries etc. )

So, when you enter `bodies[i]`, you are reading the i-th row of data from the dataset. This is how your output from `bodies[0]` maps to the dataset:

```
bodies[0]['ID'] = 1487 
bodies[0]['Name'] = b'compactor_disk'
bodies[0]['Orientation'] = (0., 0., 0., 1.)
```

And, based on the output from `h5dump` this is how the output for `bodies[2]` *should* map to the dataset:

```
bodies[2]['ID'] = 1489
bodies[2]['Name'] = b'lid'
bodies[2]['Orientation'] = (0, 0, 0, 1) 
Note they look like ints and not floats - not sure if that is a problem.
```

As @hpaulj notes, the `'Lua control functions'` output looks different for the 2 rows. bodies[2] has a zero length array, and that could be the problem.

You can access the data in each field/column individually (by name). Create a loop and see if you can isolate which field causes the problem. The code below is the way you can do that:

```
with h5py.File('h5Test.pph', 'r') as h5f:
    bodies = h5f['Bodies']
    for field in bodies.dtype.names:
        print('reading field:',field)
        temp = bodies[field]
```

Comment: I think you and @hpaulj are definitely correct that it has to do with the lua control functions, as I now recall that I configured every body in the GUI that produced this file with a control function, except for the two that gave me errors. I was unable to use your code, as `bodies.keys()` produced an error: `AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'keys'`, and I also was unable to index by `bodies[2][0]`, etc due to the same error message I originally got. In any case, having identified the issue, do you know how can I solve or work around it?

Comment: Sorry about that. I used `.keys()` to iterate over the field names and print them. I should have used **`.dtype.names`** . The work-around is to NOT extract the lua control function data (assuming that's the culprit). Using the code above, you can access the other fields by name. For example `bodies['ID']` will give an array of all IDs and `bodies['Velocity']` will return an array of all [x,y,z] Velocity arrays. You can get a specific row and field with `bodies[2]['ID']`  and `bodies[2]['Velocity']`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! It looks like `bodies[2]['ID']` and all other such statements still cause the same error as before, but `bodies['ID'][2]` works fine, and should be a perfectly good workaround.

Comment: Interesting. From past experience, I have been able to read heterogeneous array data with either index order: `[row#]['field']` or `['field'][row#]`. I wonder why yours is different (mostly rhetorical). You should report the empty array for the  'Lua control functions' entry to the developer. It's a headache to work-around.